# Spock - How to check method invocation count on a Spy object?

Tags: unit-testing, spock

I'm having tough time get this spock test to work.

I have a Spring repo/DAO class that invokes stored procedures multiple times. I'm trying to write a unit test that validates if the SP is invoked 'x' number of times (3 invocations to createSP() method).

```
public class PlanConditionRepositoryImpl{

    ....

    public void write() {
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            createSP(new ConditionGroup(), new Condition()).call();
        }
    }

    protected StoredProcedure<Void> createSP(ConditionGroup planConditionGroup, Condition planCondition) {
        return new StoredProcedure<Void>()
                .jdbcTemplate(getJdbcTemplate())
                .schemaName(SCHEMA_NAME);
    }
}
```

However the below implementation is not doing that. How do I achieve the invocation count check? Or how do I avoid calling the actual implementation of `createSP()` method.

```
def write(){
    def repo = Spy(PlanConditionRepositoryImpl){
        createSP(_, _) >> Spy(StoredProcedure){
            call() >> {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
    }
    when:
    repo.write()

    then:
    3 * repo.createSP(_, _)
}
```

This is how I solved it using a hack. But is there a solution using Spock's interaction-based testing without introducing an extra variable?

```
def "spec"() {
    given:
    def count = 0
    def spy = Spy(PlanConditionRepositoryImpl){
        createSP(_, _) >> {count++}
    }

    when:
    spy.write()

    then:
    count == 3
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is a partial mock, have a look at the [docs](https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#PartialMocks). However as I said partial mocking is basically bad practice and may indicate a bad design:

> (Think twice before using this feature. It might be better to change
>   the design of the code under specification.)

And about partial mocking:

```
// this is now the object under specification, not a collaborator
def persister = Spy(MessagePersister) {
  // stub a call on the same object
  isPersistable(_) >> true
}

when:
persister.receive("msg")

then:
// demand a call on the same object
1 * persister.persist("msg")
```

Here's how the test should be written:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class Test extends Specification {
    def "spec"() {
        given:    
        def mock = Mock(StoredProcedure)
        def spy = Spy(PlanConditionRepositoryImpl) 

        when:
        spy.write()

        then:
        3 * spy.createSP() >> mock
        3 * mock.run()
    }
}

class PlanConditionRepositoryImpl {

    void write() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            createSP().run()
        }
    }

    StoredProcedure createSP() {
        new StoredProcedure()    
    }
}

class StoredProcedure {
    def run() {}
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid `PlanConditionRepositoryImpl` is in Java. So I can't use Closure return type for createSP.

Comment: It's just an example, return what is needed.

Comment: And (BTW) you can return an instance of `Closure` from java - you just need to include groovy dependency and use appropriate syntax.

Comment: I tried executing your code and it calls `createSP()` in `PlanConditionRepositoryImpl` 3 times. But what I'm looking for is different. I don't the actual implementation of the `createSP()` method invoked. How can I replace it with a custom closure in Groovy test case and ensure it is called 3 times?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. The spec I provided verifies if `createSP` method was invoked three times. If you chnage `3 *` to `4 *` you will see the test fails. Please clarify what you need to achieve or even provide a failing test.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. What I'm trying to ask is, on the Spy object, instead of calling the concrete implementation of a method in it, how do I pass in a custom implementation from Groovy.

Comment: Sorry, still don't get it. If you don't want to call a concrete implementation you'd rather need a `Mock` or a `Stub`. But you can't both mock a class and test it - it doesn't make sense. What I can suggest is to move the `createSP` method outside of `PlanConditionRepositoryImpl` (it may be a `SPFactory` e.g.), then you can mock it and return whatever you need and it'll be better designed + easier to test. I may still help you, but I need to understand what you need to test/do.

Comment: The unit test I'm intending to write needs to ensure the following: when `write()` method is called, then check `createSP()` is called 'n' number of times irrespective of the input or output. It so happens, my `createSP()` method has external DB dependency.  So my thought process was to use a Spy and replace `createSP` concrete impl with some mock implementation. I tried Mock, Stub and Spy and yet I'm not able to get the desired results.

Comment: Please see the original question with the hack I used to get around it.

Comment: @MFIhsan, I've completely rebuilt my response. Hope it solves your problem now. But mind what I wrote about design.

Comment: Excellent. This should do @Opal. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Ask your mates to upvote :D Glad, it's finally worked out.